Style of singing called when two singers sing past each other and then reconvene
I'm looking for the term used to describe when two singers are singing different lyrics, but certain words are either the same or rhyme. I can best describe the visuals of such singing as a double helix. The singers are singing past each other, but then meet at a certain pace.
With my very limited knowledge of music theory, I thought this might be an aria or a recitative, but neither of those quite match.
Some examples (with timestamps) of what I'm talking about would be:
The Moldy Peaches' "Steak for Chicken". 


Bitter Ruin's "Trust". 


Miracle Musical's "Variations on a Cloud". 


I'm hoping there is a word or term for this because I'd love to find more songs with this kind of sound.

This is a type of contrapuntal singing, from "counterpoint" meaning melodic lines with contrasting rhythms, which is itself a type of polyphony, meaning "multiple sounds." I found this similar question on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory/comments/mqlz09/is_there_a_technical_term_for_when_a_song_has_two/ and they suggest a couple of other terms: Quodlibet, which is more often an mashup of independent songs, and polytextuality, meaning "multiple words." They also have some good examples.
I enjoy this technique as well, but it's quite rare in pop music, probably because of its inherent confusion. Run Come See, Jerusalem has it, but only in relatively brief moments of overlap. On the other hand, it's a common technique in musical theater, typically when two or more songs or melodies introduced separately are combined for a showstopper. Examples include "One More Day" from Le Miz, "Lida Rose/Sweet and Low" and "Pick-a-Little/Goodnight Ladies" from Music Man, "We Don't Talk about Bruno" from Encanto, and one of my favorites, the title song from Man of La Mancha. PDQ Bach (Peter Schickle) parodies this technique with his "Ground Rounds" where the seemingly independent lyrics yield naughty double entendres together.
You'll also often hear a variant of this in Black American gospel songs, where independent lyrical lines can be improvised by multiple lead singers at the same time, typically over a repeating ending refrain. You'll also hear it sometimes in pop music that has a gospel influence, such as in Michael Jackson's Man in the Mirror.

This is definitely what I was looking for, thank you! I've been looking for this for years.

@BeeH. You might also enjoy this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jr478w--dpE

Counterpoint covers a lot of possibilities as does polyphony in general.  I'm also not quite sure any examples are polyrhymic as it's typically used when the meter can be perceived as different not just two different rhythms happening at once ( think triplets vs straight eight notes).  As for the specific term, I don't think Quodlibet fits unless they are from other sources. If they are lines from the same song it could be viewed as a round, but the synchronization would be outside of that. It just seems like two different melodic approaches together.

Also yes maybe not inside pop music often, polyphony in general is a well used technique that was the go to for a lot of pieces of music. Almost any piece written for a string quartet or choir will have some element of polyphony and pieces like fugues were written with that as a goal. Even something popular like Bohemian Rhapsody can be viewed as polyphonic without necessarily being as rhymically independent. Something like Mozart's Requiem may be more in line with what the OP is looking for.

@Dom I removed the material on polyrhythms. I not perceiving any other disagreement with what I said in your comments, but if you have a better answer, please feel free to post it.
